# Purpose of id in PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity

Tags: webauthn

When you call `navigator.credentials.create` to generate a new credential, it is required that you include a `[PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity][1]` with an id in your `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions`. The spec says this id must be used for authentication and authorization decisions, but when you call `navigator.credentials.get` you don't pass in this value in the `PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions`. You only need the credential IDs for the credentials you will allow to sign the challenge.

If I already have a unique customer identifier on the backend to associate each generated credential with and can use this to fetch the correct credential ID, does it really matter what value I use for the userId of the PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I already have a unique customer identifier on the backend to associate each generated credential with and can use this to fetch the correct credential ID, does it really matter what value I use for the userId of the PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity?

For 2FA and Passwordless, you probably don't need to worry so much about it. As you said you already have a relationship in your database back to a user record by credential ID, and a user will have necessarily identified themselves via username/email/etc... to get far enough to complete 2FA or Passwordless authentication.

`user.id`, [also known as the `userHandle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#user-handle), becomes most important when you [require discoverable credentials](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictionary-authenticatorSelection) during registration. These types of credentials get stored internally in an authenticator in a map with a key of `(rpID, userHandle)`. You have to be careful with these because an authenticator will *override* an existing discoverable credential if you allow a user to register the same authenticator again and specify the same value for `user.id`.

On the flip side, discoverable credentials allow for "usernameless" authentication. The value of [`userHandle` you get back from `navigator.credentials.get()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-authenticatorassertionresponse-userhandle) will be how you as an RP know what the user's ID is in lieu of them telling you beforehand via username/email/etc... because it will be the same value as `user.id` you passed into `navigator.credentials.create()`.